# How can I convert 1 quad to 2 triangle

Tags: vertices

I have a plane with 4 vertices, and I want to convert it to a mesh, that has two triangles and 6 vertices.

How can I do that in blender?

[image]

Comment: you want to separate the 2 triangles? You can select the 2 opposite vertices, press J, then V to separate

Comment: no, I just want to make 2 triangles with 6 vertices from a quad.

Comment: In Edit mode select two opposite vertices and hit the J key.

Comment: But the problem is when I export it as obj i just have 4 vertices in the model

Comment: yes, after J, keep the edge selected and press V, it will separate the 2 triangles (even though it still looks like one quad)

Comment: Thanks, it worked well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the 2 opposite vertices, press <kbd>J</kbd> to join, then <kbd>V</kbd> to separate, it will give you 2 distinct triangles (even though it still looks like one quad).